# Arrange data in vector issue

Tags: c++, vector

```
class CAnalizeTime {

private:

    vector<CService> m_vData( string m_strSellers );

    sort(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end());


};
```

`CService` is another class that I created and it holds the string `m_strSellers`

I have to create a vector and arrange it by sellers

The error I get is this `syntax error : identifier 'm_vData'`

Comment: You are trying to do the sorting in the definition of the class. The class definition is only to specify what functions and variables the class will have. You need to put the sort inside one of those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
vector<CService> m_vData( string m_strSellers );
```

Is a wrong attempt to declare a member variable. Just do this:

```
vector<CService> m_vData;
```

Also, the statement:

```
sort(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end());
```

Cannot be violently put in a class definition just like that. This is a *statement* that must be part of a *function*. For instance:

```
class CAnalizeTime {

    // ...

    void sort_my_vector() 
    { 
        sort(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end()); 
    }

    vector<CService> m_vData;
};
```

I am not sure what you meant to do in your original class definition, but you should definitely remove that statement from there and put it somewhere appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The line that calls `sort` needs to appear inside a function (perhaps a member function of your class). It cannot appear directly inside a class declaration.

Comment: I believe the OP actually meant `m_vData` to be a data member. But I understand the confunsion, since the question is not clear at all.

Comment: OMG, I did it again! I edited someone else's answer by mistake... I'm sorry!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a function inside a class body

```
sort(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end());
```

So you need to shift that code inside function body.